# Loopback 3 pure SQL query with params not working with question marks (with Solution)

Tags: mysql, loopback

My query was like:

```
let query = `SELECT id, name FROM students WHERE school_code = "${schoolCode}" AND name REGEXP "${text}" `;
```

**And with params:**

```
let params = [ schoolCode, text ];
let query = `SELECT id, name FROM students WHERE school_code = "?" AND name REGEXP "?" `

Model.dataSource.connector.query(query, params, (err, res) => {} );
```

**And it wouldn't work**

(Solution below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought maybe it was the REGEXP but

### The Solution Was:

to remove quotes around the question marks.

**e.g., this worked:**

```
let params = [ schoolCode, text ];
let query = `SELECT id, name FROM students WHERE school_code = ? AND name REGEXP ? `

Model.dataSource.connector.query(query, params, (err, res) => {} );
```